# Explicit construction of $(\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}) \rtimes _{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

I am new to group theory and I wanted to explore further the concept of external semidirect product by constructing
$(\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}) \rtimes _{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ for a particular homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}_{2} \to Aut( \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) $. Since any homomorphism sends identity to identity, we need only to determine $\varphi(1)$. 
I've chosen $\alpha \in Aut( \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) $ such that $\alpha(1,0) = (2,2)$ and $\alpha(0,1) = (2,1)$ and I've checked that this is indeed an automorphism. So $\varphi(1) := \alpha$ 
Next, I wanted to determine the order of an element in this new group according to the rule
$$ (h_1,k_1)\circ (h_2,k_2) = (h_1 \phi(k_1)h_2,k_1 k_2)$$
for the general product $H \rtimes _{\phi} K$ with homomorphism $\phi$. I've got: 
$((0,1),1)\circ((0,1),1)= ((0,1) + (2,1),0) = ((2,2),0)$ 
Next, since $\alpha(2,2) = \alpha( (1,0) + (1,0) + (0,1) + (0,1) ) = \alpha(1,0) + \alpha(1,0) + \alpha(0,1) + \alpha(0,1) = (2,2) + (2,2) + (2,1) + (2,1) = (2,0)$  
we have
$((0,1),1)\circ((2,2),0)= ((0,1) + (2,0),1)=((2,1),1)$ 
Finally, by the same argument 
$((0,1),1)\circ((2,1),1) = ((0,1) + (0,2),0) = ((0,0),0)$ 
so somehow I've got an element of order 4 in a group of order 18, which is clearly impossible. I've checked each step several times and I can't see my mistake. Or am I wrong in assuming that *any* homomorphism will work?

Comment: I take it $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are the same thing.

Comment: You have to ensure that the order of $\phi(1)$ divides $2$. As far as I can see $\alpha$ has order $4$, so it can't be $\phi(1)$. [for any homomorphism the order of $f(x)$ divides the order of $x$]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @ancientmathematician nailed it (+1). We can further classify the possibilities a bit more by observing that $\phi(1)$ is a linear transformation from $\Bbb{Z}_3^2$ to itself. Because it has order two (in the non-trivial cases), it is diagonalizable. And the possible eigenvalues are $\pm1$ (both viewed as elements of the field $\Bbb{Z}_3$). It follows that the isomorphism type of the group depends on the multiplicity of $-1$ as an eigenvalue. With that piece of information given $\phi(1)$ is determined up to conjugation by an automorphism of $\Bbb{Z}_3^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your chosen $\alpha$ has order $4$. Therefore it cannot be $\phi(1)$, since that must have order dividing $2$.